# Execute multiple commands from shell to docker container

Tags: linux, bash, mongodb, shell, docker

I am trying to do in one command, do a bash from docker container, open mongo and make a request with something like

> 'db.test.find({});'

I am reading from others similar post without success.

This is the command that I am executing.

> docker exec -it mongoDB bash -c 'mongo ; use test; db.test.find({})'

And that command give me that

> bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token {}'
>
> bash: -c: line 0:mongo ; use test; db.test.find({})'

It is that possible?

I hope that you can help me.

Regards,

Roth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually possibla using a file to execute multiple commands. Put your mongo script into a file.

Example:

```
myFile.js
```

File content:

```
use myDB
show collections
```

Then you can execute this file with

```
mongo < myFile.js
```

In your situation:

```
docker exec -it mongoDB bash -c 'mongo < myFile.js'
```

Don't forget to copy this file into your docker container.

You can [read more here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to copy the script into the container.

You can simply run :

```
docker exec -it mongoDB bash -c 'mongo' < myFile.js
```

Comment: `docker exec -i`, not `-it`.